# Sync Folders on Different machines using Microsoft.Synchronization library

Tags: c#, .net, synchronization

I am working on a windows application which should sync folders from server to different machines [clients] hence different networks using Microsoft.Synchronization library, is that doable and how should provide the destination folder along with the username and password?

If this is not doable is there any other way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: am assuming you're pertaining to mapped drives in a local network? you can't pass authentication credentials for the network drives via the file sync providers,so you will have to establish the mapping before you make a call to sync.